# PHP Auto Login after Registration

Tags: php, database, forms, automation, registration

I'm having some issues with a request from my boss.

I'm using the http://www.html-form-guide.com/ Registration forms he has created for use (I've attached the link just in case anyone want to use or look at it)

So I'm pretty new to PHP, but I've been gaining a crazy amount of knowledge.

Here is my problem - I need to make this form Register the user than **Login Automatically**. (This form has a Email confirmation system)

So I've managed to bypass the Email Confirmation and get the user to register, but I can't seem to figure out how to get auto login.

Here is what I've traced in the code:

```
    function RegisterUser()
{
    if(!isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
       return false;
    }

    $formvars = array();

    if(!$this->ValidateRegistrationSubmission())
    {
        return false;
    }

    $this->CollectRegistrationSubmission($formvars);

    if(!$this->SaveToDatabase($formvars))
    {
        return false;
    }

    /*if(!$this->SendUserConfirmationEmail($formvars))
    {
        return false;
    }*/

    $this->SendAdminIntimationEmail($formvars);

    $this->AutoLogin($formvars);// My call

    return true;
}
```

This will pull in the **name, email and password** - put them in an array then send it off for validation and sanitation. I've placed a call function here.

After which I'll need to manually login with:

```
function Login()
{
    if(empty($_POST['email']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Email is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }
    if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($email,$password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $email;

    return true;
}
```

So I took the last portion of the login function and made:

```
    function AutoLogin(&$formvars)
{
    $email = trim($formvars['email']);
    $password = trim($formvars['password']);

    if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }       
    if(!$this->CheckLoginInDB($email,$password))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $email;

    return true;
}
```

I did an echo $email; echo $password; exit; test and I can see that the email and password are appearing. But the "Session" (I think) is not starting or the **Check Login** is not getting the data.

```
    function CheckLogin()
{
     if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start(); }

     $sessionvar = $this->GetLoginSessionVar();

     if(empty($_SESSION[$sessionvar]))
     {
        return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Now I see the is a CheckLoginInDB which is:

```
    function CheckLoginInDB($email,$password)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }          
    $email = $this->SanitizeForSQL($email);
    $pwdmd5 = md5($password);
    $qry = "Select name, email, pagecode, welcome from $this->tablename where email='$email' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";

    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The email or password does not match");
        return false;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['pagecode_of_user'] = $row['pagecode'];
    $_SESSION['welcome_user'] = $row['welcome'];

    return true;
}
```

What I can gather from this, its just a standard checking the database to see if this user exists and returning the results.

I've searching through stackoverflow and can't seem to see an answer to my problem.

I looked into Cookies, but I don't think that is something I really need here.

My questions are:

**How can I make this bad boy start the session on registration?**

**Is my thinking on calling the AutoLogin(&$formvars) the right idea?**

**Have I gone wrong with this AutoLogin function syntax?**

Just in case here is the GetLoginSessionVar():

```
    function GetLoginSessionVar()
{
    $retvar = md5($this->rand_key);
    $retvar = 'usr_'.substr($retvar,0,10);
    return $retvar;
}
```

It's a pity I can't attached the file I'm working on, but if you need any further code snippets let me know and I'll be sure to Edit this straight away!

Comment: First, you've to minimize the code and describe the problem theoretically. If required then post the code later.

Comment: I don't mean to sound harsh here, but I wouldn't waste anymore time with this than you already have. This code is totally unsafe to be used in a live environment. First the `mysql_` api and then MD5. Use a prepared statement and `password_hash()`.

Comment: @YashParekh Hmmm, everytime I've seen a question of this site, I see that everyone complains that they didn't put in the code. I tried to be as thorough as possible.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see what you mean, mysqli is out, but at this point I wouldn't be able to completely re-code this entire thing and I have no knowledge of prepared statements yet. I think this is pretty safe to use as you can't inject into the database.

Comment: @PowerCat If you think it's safe, then go for it. Personally, I think you're going to get hacked somewhere down the line, sorry to say.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Luckly this is just a temp site that will be up for like 6 months for a set amount of users from a company of pencil pushers. If it was something I was building personally I would completely do it from the MySqli and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

> But the "Session" (I think) is not starting or the Check Login is not
>   getting the data.
>   Is my thinking on calling the AutoLogin(&$formvars) the right idea?
>   Have I gone wrong with this AutoLogin function syntax?

It's not something wrong with the syntax, otherwise the code wouldn't even be compiled. Nevertheless I believe it's not the right idea.

You need to understand what's the problem before trying to fix it.
Debug the code. Use xdebug. If it's installed and active, you can use IDEs (e.g.: Visual Studio Code) to easily debug the code. Add breakpoints where you suspect there's something wrong.

If you don't want to use xdebug, you can add temporarily echoes or var_dumps to check if some areas of the code are processed and check some relevant values.

Also enable all errors reports and use a logger.
If the session is started after any output, there should be some warning.
Handle the errors and throw exceptions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php
- https://jtreminio.com/2012/07/xdebug-and-you-why-you-should-be-using-a-real-debugger/
- [session_start() works after output being sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711282/session-start-works-after-output-being-sent)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

You don't need to use the & in `AutoLogin(&$formvars)` if you're not changing the argument $formvars (you're just reading it).

You don't need to set session variables with all the user data. Create some structure (a class, an array, ...) with the user data outside those function and change those. `AutoLogin` should update that structure, something like this:

```
<?php

if (!$_SESSION) {
    session_start();
}

$currentUser = array();

function getUserFromID($userID)
{
    //TODO implement function
    return $user;
}

function AutoLogin()
{
    global $currentUser;
    if(!empty($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        return false;
    }

    $user = getUserFromID($_SESSION['userID']);
    if (empty($user)) {
        return false;
    }
    $currentUser = $user;
    return true;
}
```

Maybe the session is not initialised before CheckLoginInDB is invoked (make `var_dump($_SESSION);` to check it). Use the $_SESSION only to save the user ID (or email) and read it to retrieve the user data.

Comment: Managed to debug it all, managed to see that the one page was receiving all the data, but the data wasn't being used.

But we came up with a way to fix it, by calling another page to run the function.

Thanks for your answer!