# Adding CSRF to formtoemailpro.php

Tags: php, forms, csrf

Following the post at: https://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/10/16/how-to-csrf-protect-all-your-forms/

I am trying and failing to add the code to formtoemailpro.php https://formtoemail.com/developer_pricing.php

I add the key generator to the form page:

```
//Generate a key, print a form:
$key = sha1(microtime());
$_SESSION['csrf'] = $key;
```

And the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" />
```

But I cannot add  the following to formtoemailpro.php and have it work. I have put the top half at the top of the form and the '}' at the bottom as well as adding the 'if(!isset' expession along with the other similar elements of the processing part of the form and I fail.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            //Here we parse the form
if(!isset($_SESSION['csrf']) || $_SESSION['csrf'] !== $_POST['csrf'])
 throw new RuntimeException('CSRF attack');
 //Do the rest of the processing here
}
```

I am sorry for my ignorance, please can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: display value of `$_POST['csrf']` and value of `$_SESSION['csrf']` before `if` and you understand where is the problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understated your problem, this is what you need to do:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    //Here we parse the form
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['csrf']) || $_SESSION['csrf'] !== $_POST['csrf']){
    throw new RuntimeException('CSRF attack');
 //Do the rest of the processing here
}
```

Make sure you place the "{", "}", on code blocks.

Also, make sure `$_SESSION['csrf'] = $key;` is called before any output. (Echo, print, etc...). Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711282/session-start-works-after-output-being-sent) Q&A about sessions.

Comment: Thank you. My problem is adding the code to the form processor. I canot really post the script here as it is a paid for thing and I don't want to make it available for free, however, it strats with: <?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); Theee are a number of things defined $my_email = "my@email.address"; etc Then the form continues with: $my_email = "my@email.address"; and ends with exit;

}

?> Sorry - I guess that is not much help

Comment: @user2135841 Try and change "error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);" to error_reporting(false); as you will see in the link, you should add session_start(); and all of the $_session[] calls must be before any file output. (btw - Please don't forget to upvote and select the answer as selected if all goes well :)

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid I am not technicaly up to this.

Comment: Happy to help @user2135841, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted and upvote. Thanks and good luck!